# Korn - Mayhem Festival 2014 Documentary

Tags: metal

I've been watching this Korn documentary about their performance in the Mayhem Festival. Korn songs are amazing, but the hole soundtrack is great, and I want to know the name of other songs and bands used as the soundtrack of the documentary.

where can I get the whole soundtrack? I mean all the songs from the documentary, not only Korn ones?﻿ Can someone help me to identify them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The video was directed and edited by Sébastien Paquet.

http://www.klown.org/index.php

His telephone number in Los Angeles and email address are right here:

http://www.klown.org/contact.php

Why not contact him yourself and ask him for a list of all the music used?

Answer (score 1):

Here are links to the full setlists for all the bands that played the main stage at the July 5th, San Bernadino, CA venue (where the video provided was filmed). This doesn't directly answer your question, but it does cover everything in the video plus more.

[Korn](http://www.setlist.fm/setlist/korn/2014/san-manuel-amphitheater-san-bernardino-ca-33c1f8c1.html)

[Avenged Sevenfold](http://www.setlist.fm/setlist/avenged-sevenfold/2014/san-manuel-amphitheater-san-bernardino-ca-2bc1fcfa.html)

[Asking Alexandria](http://www.setlist.fm/setlist/asking-alexandria/2014/san-manuel-amphitheater-san-bernardino-ca-23c1f8c7.html)

[Trivium](http://www.setlist.fm/setlist/trivium/2014/san-manuel-amphitheater-san-bernardino-ca-23c1f8bb.html)

I didn't watch the whole video at normal speed, so its possible that I missed it, but I believed all of the set filming was done at the main stage. You can also view a list of the other bands that played the smaller stages if you'd like some similar artists to look into.

[Mayhem Festival 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayhem_Festival_2014)